# Forcefully killing a thread that is attempting, but has not succeeded, in accessing a resource

Tags: java, multithreading, jython

My dev Hadoop/MapR cluster is down for an upgrade today, and the moment it went down I tried to access HBase to see what would happen.

The following Jython/HBase code simply hanged forever (i.e., 5 minutes) without returning:

```
table = HTable(connection, name)
# @connection: HBaseConfiguration
# @name: String: name of HBase Table
```

(The equivalent Java code is `HTable table = HTable(connection, name)`)

On the server it just printing this over and over:

```
Thread: 24986 ContainerLookup RPC error Connection reset by peer(104) to CLDB xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:7222 for cid 2049 failed
```

After 5 minutes I stopped it and tried again, and this time it threw a `Could not create FileClient`

However, I am thinking of creating a method to be run in a thread that will make the call to initialize the table. If this thread takes longer than 30 seconds to complete, I assume that the thread is hanging and has been unable to access the resource, and I forcefully kill the thread.

I know that it is bad to forcefully kill threads that are accessing a resource, like a database. However, the thread would only attempt to get a connection to the table and not perform any actions on it.

Would it be OK to forcefully kill a thread that is "only attempting to get access to a resource" as opposed to one that already has accessed a resource?

Comment: Is there a timeout option in the API?

Comment: @bayou.io Here is the relevant [code](https://hbase.apache.org/0.94/apidocs/src-html/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/HTable.html#line.133), in which I don't see a timeout option.